# Filtration using awk

Tags: awk

I have a text as follows

```
------|----------|----------
ABC       12             40  
------|----------|----------
ABW       12             1 
AB        12             40  
ABD       123            1 
ABG       1234           40
```

and need to get the following

```
ABC       12             40 
AB        12             40 
ABG       1234           40
```

I need to use the number 40 as basis in columns to get the filtration working ?

Comment: `awk '$3 == 40' file` (there is no `{ ... }` rule following the condition which invokes the default rule -- `print`) Or with `grep`, you can use `grep '40\s*$' file`

Comment: thanks a lot -  worked - was trying awk 'print $3 =40'

Comment: Oh... that `=` verses `==` -- will byte you even when you are trying to avoid it. Good luck with your scripting.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO). [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `grep '40\s*$' file` would work for this example data, but would not it provide false positive if say there will be `240` in that column? I am also confused as this question has only `awk` tag. Does `awk` tag automatically grant access `grep`? If yes please provide table with information which tag does grant access to what other tools.

Comment: Good eye, you can do `grep '\s40\s*$' file` and it would isolate only `40` at the end of the line (regardless of trailing whitespace)

Answer (score 0):

I would use GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
------|----------|----------
ABC       12             40  
------|----------|----------
ABW       12             1 
AB        12             40  
ABD       123            1 
ABG       1234           40
```

then

```
awk '40==$3' file.txt
```

output

```
ABC       12             40  
AB        12             40  
ABG       1234           40
```

Explanation: only print lines where value of 3rd column (`$3`) equals (`==`) `40`.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*